# streamlit image style in a python project need to change the aspect-ratio

Tags: python, css, streamlit

I am using **streamlit** for the first time and I want to modify the **images style** , I found this function on the streamlit documentation

```
st.image(image, caption=None, width=None, use_column_width=None, clamp=False, channels="RGB", output_format="auto")
```

is there a way to change the ***height as well*** , or any other way to change the ***aspect-ratio***.
I tried change the style through a css sheet , but for some reason sometimes its not loading , so I would like to change it directly through streamlit .

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use PIL to achieve that.

```py
from PIL import Image
import base64

def resize_images(image_path, width, height):
    img = Image.open(image_path)
    image = base64.b64encode(img).decode("utf-8")

    resized_image = image.resize((width, height))
    return resized_image

my_image = resize_images(image_path="\img\path", width=25, height=30)
st.image(my_image)
```

Comment: I cant cause the images are decoded so they are in binary format so the resize function doesn't work here

Comment: Yeah I think you can, by decoding them first before further process. So I will edit the answer so you can try it out.

Comment: Thank you , here is the code I have so far ``` img = base64.b64decode(generatedImgs[index])
                st.image(img, width = 800, output_format= "JPEG") ```